# SQL Update ceasing to work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to update a mysql database. That has become a common practice for me, but for some reason with no error, it just doesn't work. The only thing I have never done is compare against 2 variables(in this case, ID && Name)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$duty = $_POST['duty'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$url = $_POST['url'];

 $insert = "UPDATE vendors SET name = '$_POST[name]', duty = '$_POST[duty]', number = '$_POST[number]', url = '$_POST[url]' WHERE id = '$id' && name = '$name'";

$result=mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

 if ($result) {
 header("location:**HIDDEN**");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *sigh*, http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: try by putting a die($insert); after your $insert statement and use the query printed directly in your database client, say phpmyadmin, this way you will be able to debug and know that what is going wrong.

Comment: if you use that code in production R.I.P for all your sensitive data...

Comment: Lol I promise to sanitize my data this is temporary.

Comment: please check your codes to phpmyadmin or mysql console.. your code seems to be correct... what are your trying to do? maybe your are updating a row that does not pass to your WHERE clause criteria

Comment: He had not mentioned $id any where before.

Comment: and anyways where is the $id?

Comment: The id comes from a session variable above. I know that code to work which is why I did not publish it

Comment: you can debug your code in phpmyadmin console portion . where you can find the exact error.. then come back here with error...

Comment: @Tyler Radlick — Don't write hacky, temporary query code. Unescaped data can break your query. Go direct to PDO and bound parameters. Do not use `mysql_query`. Do not generate SQL by mashing together strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this instead:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$duty = $_POST['duty'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$url = $_POST['url'];

 $insert = "UPDATE `vendors` SET `name` = '{$_POST['name']}', `duty` = '{$_POST['duty']}', `number` = '{$_POST['number']}', `url` = '{$_POST['url']}' WHERE (`id` = '$id' AND `name` = '$name')";

$result = @mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

 header("location:**HIDDEN**");
```

It should now work. Notify me if there still is a problem.

Comment: Now give it a try please. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No luck :/ I don't understand whats going on.

Comment: try it now, sorry for the inconvenience once more.

Comment: Still no luck. I don't think its your code though. Something odd is going on.

Comment: No thats whats odd. Everything works fine it just doesn't change anything and I have this same code elsewhere working just fine.

Comment: Just edit your question and add it in. Then I might be able to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10825/discussion-between-think123-and-tyler-radlick)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `&&`, you should use `AND` to add another where-condition.

Answer (score 0):

replace && with AND and you should be good

Comment: No , && is not a SQL operator

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is wrong. Following is the correct one.

The way you have used the variables is wrong.

You had not written any code for $id. What is that?

```
$insert = "UPDATE vendors SET name = '".$_POST['name']."', duty = '".$_POST['duty']."', number = '".$_POST['number']."', url = '".$_POST['url']."' WHERE id = '$id' AND name = '$name'";
```

Comment: Its an Integer Name is the vendors name

Comment: But your suppose to pass it from html form or you need to get it via code. But you have done nothing for $id, so how can you use it in where clause of the query.

Comment: I know this, there is more code above this for connection and for getting the data from the url. I check that the data is coming from the url correctly via php echo

Comment: @Tyler Radlick kindly take that echo display string and check in phpmyadmin. Lets see what error you will get